# вывести все данные из бд из конкретного столбца

Tags: python, sql, discord, sqlite3, discord.py

```
@clan.command()
    async def profile(self, ctx):
        author = ctx.message.author
        clan_id = cur.execute(f'SELECT ClanId FROM UserClans WHERE UserId = {author.id}').fetchone()
        cur.execute(f'SELECT UserName FROM UserClans WHERE {clan_id[0]}')
        users = cur.fetchall()
        l = []
        l.append(users)
        return print(l)
```

Мне нужно вывести всех юзеров клана, но таким способом выводит только первого в списке.
Есть ли способ вывести всех без цикла?

Answer (score 0):

`append()` добавляет только один элемент

Для добавления множества элементов используйте `extend()`

```
@clan.command()
    async def profile(self, ctx):
        author = ctx.message.author
        clan_id = cur.execute(f'SELECT ClanId FROM UserClans WHERE UserId = {author.id}').fetchone()
        cur.execute(f'SELECT UserName FROM UserClans WHERE {clan_id[0]}')
        users = cur.fetchall()
        l = []
        l.extend(users) # одно изменение
        return print(l)
```